# Question on TikZlings

Tags: tikzlings

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzlings-bears}
\begin{document}
Foo \tikz{\bear} bar 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\bear
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got errors. The following are log.file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.9.22)  13 APR 2019 22:43
entering extended mode
**animals11.tex

("D:\[018]Books on LaTex\Examples downloaded froom Texample\drawing animals by 
using tikzlings\animals11.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for loaded.
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("D:\[018]Books on LaTex\Examples downloaded froom Texample\drawing animals by 
using tikzlings\tikzlings-bears.sty"
Package: tikzlings-bears 2019/04/07 v0.2 Draw teddy bears in TikZ

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks19
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks21
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty
("D:\[018]Books on LaTex\Examples downloaded froom Texample\drawing animals by 
using tikzlings\pgfkeys.sty"
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks22
\pgffor@toks=\toks23
))
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@tempbox=\box34
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths
.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("D:\[018]Books on LaTex\Examples downloaded froom Texample\drawing animals by 
using tikzlings\tikzlings-addons.sty"
Package: tikzlings-addons 2019/04/07 v0.2 Draw additional items for the tikzlin
gs

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarypattern
s.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)

(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex
File: pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/03/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.13)
))

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/top hat/.forward to' and
 I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/straw hat/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/magic hat/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/magic stars/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/queen crown/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/king crown/.forward to' 
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/book colour/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/book color/.forward to' 
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/bookcolor/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/sign post/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/sign colour/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/sign color/.forward to' 
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/signcolor/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/sign back/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/bubble colour/.forward t
o' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/bubble color/.forward to
' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/bubblecolor/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/david likes pineapple pi
zza/.forward to' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/ice cream/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/flavour a/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/flavour b/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/flavour c/.forward to' a
nd I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/crystal ball/.forward to
' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/magic want/.forward to' 
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/rolling pin/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/light saber/.forward to'
 and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/egg a/.forward to' and I
 am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/egg b/.forward to' and I
 am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/egg c/.forward to' and I
 am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/thing/umbrella closed/.forward
 to' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.295 }

(That was another \errmessage.)

))
("D:\[018]Books on LaTex\Examples downloaded froom Texample\drawing animals by 
using tikzlings\animals11.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count107
\scratchdimen=\dimen148
\scratchbox=\box35
\nofMPsegments=\count108
\nofMParguments=\count109
\everyMPshowfont=\toks24
\MPscratchCnt=\count110
\MPscratchDim=\dimen149
\MPnumerator=\count111
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count112
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks25
) [1

{C:/CTEX/UserData/pdftex/config/pdftex.map{Unicode.sfd}{UGBK.sfd}}]
("D:\[018]Books on LaTex\Examples downloaded froom Texample\drawing animals by 
using tikzlings\animals11.aux") ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9866 strings out of 495354
 190282 string characters out of 3183859
 242221 words of memory out of 3000000
 12880 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,5n,57p,465b,500s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on animals11.pdf (1 page, 13158 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: `LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>`. Your system is completly outdated. Your format is old, your pgf is old (from 2010). The tikzlings package won't work there.

Answer (score 3):

Ti*k*Zlings is a package built on Ti*k*Z, therefore, you have to use "Ti*k*Z opening commands" like `tikzpicture` environment, or `\tikz`.

Also, `tikzlings` is a superset of `tikzlings-bears`, so if you only use `\bear`, load the latter, but if you use every available animal, load the former.

Working code: (only works with up-to-date TeX distributions – weekly updates are necessary)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzlings-bears}
\begin{document}
Foo \tikz{\bear} bar 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\bear
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Bear speaking: Am I lovely? :D]

[image]

Output full page:

[image]

Comment: The Bär is waiting for a picture ...

Comment: You could also say `\tikz{\bear with me}` ;-) (+1)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [Bear speaking: I'm sorry for being late :)]

Comment: @tianxia-dd The problem is: your TeX distribution is very _old_. Please update it.

Comment: @tianxia-dd Consider accepting my answer if it helps.

Comment: In the manual of the  TikZlings package, the author uses the animals he created to number the pages. How does he do that?